# Convert NSString (eg: "2300") to NSDate (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to convert an `NSString` like this one "2300" to `NSDate` format. (Note: there is no colon after 23).

I get the string from an external web service. I need to display this time in my app in 12hr format.

Thank You :)

Comment: "2300" could be anything. Are you saying that it is a time in 24 hour format (hhmm) and you want to convert it to an NSDate and then to a time string in 12 hour format?

Comment: Yes.."2300" is a time in 24hr format

Comment: you are get this type format : 11:00 PM?

Comment: what the output you need

Comment: If the string I got from the web service was "2100", then I need the out put to be like this "9:00 pm"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added here in three types , in which tyope you need choose

**Type -1**

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HHmm"];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
 NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:@"2300"];
  [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];
NSString *finalDate = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"finalDate==%@",finalDate);
```

**Type -2**

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter1 setDateFormat:@"HHmm"];
[formatter1 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
[formatter1 setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
NSDate *date1 = [formatter1 dateFromString:@"2300"];
[formatter1 setDateFormat:@"hhmm"];
NSString *finalDate1 = [formatter1 stringFromDate:date1];
NSLog(@"finalDate1==%@",finalDate1);
```

**Type -3**

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter2 setDateFormat:@"HHmm"];
[formatter2 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
[formatter2 setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
NSDate *date2 = [formatter1 dateFromString:@"2300"];
[formatter2 setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
NSString *finalDate2 = [formatter2 stringFromDate:date2];
NSLog(@"finalDate2==%@",finalDate2);
```

your get the output like

[image]

Comment: are you got the solurtion or not

Comment: This works for me thank you. :)

Comment: @AbbinVarghese - welcome

Comment: Good, complete answer (voted), although it's usually better if you provide guidance rather than complete code. (Providing complete code leads to copy/paste programming rather than real learning.)

Comment: @DuncanC - tanx a lot my bro

Comment: One thing you should add is setting the formatters' locales to the system locale in order to prevent problems if the local date format is something unusual. (See the edits to Bonnie's answer, suggested by Abizern, below.) It's less clear if you'd want to set the system locale on the output formatter. If you want the output time string to follow the conventions of the user's locale, then no. If you want a fixed format (usually only a good idea for string data transfer) then you problaby **do** want to set the output formatter to the system locale.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you question correctly, 2300 is actually 23:00 ie 11pm.
So first you need to get the date from the string, there is only way i can think of with the data your getting is to use `Substring`

```
- (NSDate*) getDateFromweb:(NSString *)dateString
{        
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HHmm"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
    NSString *pmAm = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

    return pmAm;
}
```

added system locale and timezone on suggestion from abizern.
this will also not assume the datestring to have 4 digits

Comment: This assumes that the format will always be 4 digits. Also, you don't take into account time zones or locales.

Comment: @Abizern please don't expect an answer to pass 100% test cases. its just a sudo code to get the solution. it can be optimised as per usage.

Comment: Why not just use "HHmm" instead of "HH:mm"?

Comment: The point of an answer is to be comprehensive. You're missing out some obvious things. Data and Time programming is hard, and if you aren't careful you could introduce subtle bugs that are time consuming to correct.

Comment: ok il try to improve my answer